# Center timeline/dopesheet at current time by keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut, dopesheet

Sometimes the current time bar goes off-screen in the Timeline or Dopesheet. I would like to easily recenter the timeline/dopesheet to where the current time bar is, but without changing zoom levels.

There is the <kbd>Home</kbd> shortcut that fits the timeline to the screen, but losing the zoom level is really inconvenient. Is there a keyboard shortcut for centering on the current time bar? Or a way to have the screen follow the current time bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the timeline, the cursor is, apparently, grammatically, the 'camera'?. By analogy, <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> centers the view on it. <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> centers on the selected keyframe.

Comment: Ah thank you. I am working on a laptop without a numpad, so I'll have to find something convenient to remap these to.

Comment: @tester The remap would be from the timeline header 'View' menu, with a right-click on the item. Shift-C or something makes more sense to me.. until I think it through and figure out why that's a bad idea :)